# Why do exact images not have exact descriptors?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, surf

I'm developing an image recognition application and something is bugging me.

I am working with bitonal images (documents). If I make a copy of the same image file and compare both (actually comparing a sub-region of both [the same sub region]), i don't get 100% matches using SURF. Here's part of my code:

```
public double FindPercentMatch(Bitmap obj, Bitmap scene)
{

    // get scene key points
    VectorOfKeyPoint scenePoints = GetKeyPoints((Bitmap)scene.Clone());

    // if no scene points found, no need to go any further
    if (scenePoints == null || scenePoints.Size == 0) { return 0; }

    // get object key points
    VectorOfKeyPoint objectPoints = GetKeyPoints((Bitmap)obj.Clone());            

    // if not enough object key points found vs scene key points, then match can't be close enough (since
    // you can't have more matches than scene points anyway, so don't even try to match
    if (objectPoints == null || objectPoints.Size == 0 || (scenePoints.Size / objectPoints.Size < .15)) { return 0; }

    // we have enough key points, so compute descriptors for scene and object
    Matrix<float> objectDescriptors = GetDescriptors(objectPoints,(Bitmap)obj.Clone());
    Matrix<float> sceneDescriptors = GetDescriptors(scenePoints, (Bitmap)scene.Clone());
    int objectDescriptorCount = objectDescriptors == null ? 0 : objectDescriptors.Size.Height;
    int sceneDescriptorCount = sceneDescriptors == null ? 0 : sceneDescriptors.Size.Height;

    // find matches
    int sim = FindMatches(objectDescriptors, sceneDescriptors);

    // for testing so we know how many were found so we can monitor it
    log.Debug("descriptors1 = " + objectDescriptorCount + ", 2 = " + sceneDescriptorCount + ", matches=" + sim);

    double percent = 0;
    if (sim != 0)
    {
        percent = objectDescriptorCount != 0 ? (double)sim / (double)objectDescriptorCount : 0;
        log.Debug(percent * 100 + "%");
    }
    return percent;

}

public int FindMatches(Matrix<float> dbDescriptors, Matrix<float> queryDescriptors)
{

    double uniquenessThreshold = 0.6;

    if (dbDescriptors == null || queryDescriptors == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    var indices = new Matrix<int>(queryDescriptors.Rows, 2); // matrix that will contain indices of the 2-nearest neighbors found
    var dists = new Matrix<float>(queryDescriptors.Rows, 2); // matrix that will contain distances to the 2-nearest neighbors found

    // create FLANN index with 4 kd-trees and perform KNN search over it look for 2 nearest neighbours
    var flannIndex = new Index(dbDescriptors, 4);

    flannIndex.KnnSearch(queryDescriptors, indices, dists, 2, 24);

    // for eatch match over a certain threshold, add +1 to the number of 'good' matches
    int sim = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.Rows; i++)
    {
        // filter out all inadequate pairs based on distance between pairs
        if (dists.Data[i, 0] < (uniquenessThreshold * dists.Data[i, 1]))
        {
            sim++;
        }
    }
    return sim;
}
```

The expected outcome when using FindPercentMatch on the same sub-region of an image would be 100%, but depending on the image, it may be 70%, 99%, and I've even seen 101%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have fixed my problem by using the brute force matcher instead of flann index. Also, instead of using 2nn and comparing them, I only found the first nearest neighbor and counted any that were under a certain threshold as a 'good match'. Then I divide the good matches by the total number of keypoints for the OBJECT (not the scene) so I now end up with 0-100% matches.

```
        int numberOfNearestNeighbors = 1;

        double maxDistance = .30;

        BruteForceMatcher<float> matcher = new BruteForceMatcher<float>(DistanceType.L2);

        matcher.Add(dbDescriptors);

        var indices = new Matrix<int>(queryDescriptors.Rows, numberOfNearestNeighbors);
        using (Matrix<float> dist = new Matrix<float>(queryDescriptors.Rows, numberOfNearestNeighbors))
        {
            // null = no mask, use whole image
            matcher.KnnMatch(queryDescriptors, indices, dist, numberOfNearestNeighbors, null);

            int matchesUnderMaxDistance = 0;
            float distance = 0;

            // filter matches that are too different
            for (int i = 0; i < indices.Rows; i++)
            {
                distance = dist.Data[i, 0];

                if (distance < maxDistance)
                {
                    matchesUnderMaxDistance++;
                }
            }

            return matchesUnderMaxDistance;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see your filtering doesn't result in 1-to-1 objectdescriptor - scenedescriptor (matching over a certain threshold) that is why you can get 100+ %

other thing is that the fact that "objectDescriptorCount equals sceneDescriptorCount" doesn't always mean that "objectDescriptors equals sceneDescriptors". Check the descriptors manually and if they ARE same that would mean that your processing logic is somewhere wrong (counting "sim")

hope that helps